# How many distinct bracelets can be made?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A bracelet contains at least 1 and at most 4 beads of identical size on a loop of string. Anna is making a bracelet and has 3 green, 3 blue and 3 red beads. How many distinct bracelets can she possibly make?

The way I attempted this question was by counting up the number of distinct bracelets case by case, and summed them up, but it seems like a rather inefficient way. E.g.,
1 bead --> 3 distinct bracelets
2 beads --> 3*3=9 distinct bracelets
3 beads where all beads are the same colour --> 3 distinct bracelets.
3 beads where all beads are different colours --> 3!=6 distinct bracelets.
etc..

Is there any other way to do the problem intuitively?

Comment: That's a good way. Note that for 2 beads, there are only 6 bracelets. Do you know where your error is?

Comment: There are many variations of this question. For example, are the two ends of each bead symmetric?

Comment: "*Two beads -> $3\times 3 = 9$ distinct bracelets*"  Are you sure?  Is a bracelet with a red bead followed by a blue bead not exactly the same type of bracelet as one which has a blue bead followed by a red bead?  "*Bracelets*" in combinatorics is a rather loaded word which carries with it a lot of implications about the problems they appear in, commonly that rotations of bracelets should be considered as effectively the same, similar to necklaces in combinatorics... but further bracelets are also considered the same as their reflections, unlike necklaces.

Comment: Read more about the common usage of the words "bracelet" and "necklace" in combinatorics [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)).  So... again... you will need to clarify what exact types of objects you intend to work with and whether there are any ways in which one seemingly different object should or should not be treated as "the same" as another.

Answer (score 1):

You case analysis should look more like this:

**Case 1: one bead**

With $3$ colours to choose from, there are $3$ distinct one-bead bracelets.

**Case 2: two beads**

You can have $2$ beads of the same colour or $2$ beads of a different colour. There are $3$ bracelets of the first type and $3$ of bracelets of the second type, for a total of $6$ bracelets.

**Case 3: three beads**

You can have a bracelet with one colour, two colours or three colours. There is only $1$ bracelet of three colours and $3$ bracelets of one colour. For the two-colour case, note that there were $3$ two-bead bracelets with $2$ colours; for each of these, you have $2$ possible beads you can append without changing the number of colours, for a total of $2\times 3 = 6$.

So in total, you have $1+3+6=10$ three-bead bracelets.

**Case 4: four beads**

This case analysis proceeds exactly the same way as before. There are no bracelets that can be made of one colour, as all three of any colour must have been used by this point. Given $6$ two-colour, three-bead bracelets, there are $2$ choices of bead to append for each, for a total of $12$. For three colours, there was exactly $1$ three-bead necklace; any of the three colours can be affixed to this, for a total of $3$. There are therefore $3+12=15$ four-bead bracelets.

The total number of bracelets is the sum of the number of one, two, three and four-bead bracelets, which is $3+6+10+15=34$.

Comment: No 4-bead bracelet can be made with one color here as there are only three copies of each particular colored bead.  It also is not perfectly clear yet that the OP is using their words correctly and is actually wishing to talk about "bracelets" in the same way you or I might.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh, damn it! What a rookie mistake... thanks for the heads up, I'll amend it now